# When I try to open a wordpress page on a subfolder I'am redirected to the root

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory

I really need help here.

I've this situation with two wordpress site:

**site.com**

**site.com/blog**

site.com is a live website. I want to create a new website on the subdirectory site.com/blog

I don't want a multi website.

I've created the /blog subdirectory on site.com and I've installed a fresh copy of wordpress on site.com/blog (with a new database). When I open site.com/blog homepage everything works, the wordpress back-end works, but when I try to open one of the other pages like site.com/blog/pageone.php I'am redirected to site.com/pageone.php or to an error page.

I'm currently on an Nginx server with cloud panel installed so I think I'm missing something in the .conf file.

I've tried to change the htaccess in the subfolder site.com/blog but didn't work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```